# Move Login Form closer to Header CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move the login form, from its current position upwards. It needs to be closer to the logo, I know this is because of the min height set on the header but this needs to be fixed.

[image]

On the right is how the form appears. And on the left is how it should appear.

*Please note* the change should only affect the login form.

```
.header-strip {
   background: url("../../Images/gradient.gif");
    min-width: 981px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
    min-height: 134px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.login {
    background: url("../../Images/Audi-R8-TDI.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your code and add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: It is not a good solution but try adding a negative top margin. `margin-top: -20px`

Comment: That just eats up the background image within the login form, moves things up within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

change

```
.login {
    background: url("../../Images/Audi-R8-TDI.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

to

```
.login {
    background: url("../../Images/Audi-R8-TDI.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: -20px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

this will change the distance of the login to the header and sets the login on a higher z-index

see on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/W9gcx/

Comment: that moves it closer to the header but it does not overlap the header to move closer to the logo.

Comment: then you can change the `margin: -20px 0 0 0` to maybe `margin: -50px 0 0 0`

Comment: As I mentioned previously, it just does not move up, it moves form contents up and eats the background image. I am lost as to why?

Comment: add these 3 lines of code as well: `position: relative; top: 0; z-index: 9999;`           they work, ive tested them here http://jsfiddle.net/W9gcx/

Comment: yes I have, I managed to resolve it. I just adjusted the padding-top: 10px; to padding-top: 35px. This moves the logo closer to the login form. I guess this will do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: add it where? to the form?

Comment: to the .login class, or you could just copy the code in my answer, ive already edited it

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm!, could you explain to me why it worked and why it didn't?

Comment: it changed the position atribute so it orientates on the element above, also it made the login form "higher" like it shows in this image: http://www.pas-solutions.ch/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/z-index.gif wih z-index, then it was possible to move the whole object upwars. before it also moved it upwards, but since it was the second elemen it wend under the first one, thats why your background got eaten

Answer (score 1):

Try adding margin-top for the login.

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't get anywhere close to the logo.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce your padding top til you get it as you want. currently its 50.

```
.login {
      padding: 20px 0 50px 0;
}
```

hope its helps.

Comment: thanks for that, but it doesn't move the form up. it moves the contents within the form up.

Answer (score 0):

You must set margin-top and padding-top  to 0, but also you have to set the form tag to display inline

Comment: is this on the form? or header?

Comment: Try doing in the form, but you must pay attention that you need to set padding and margin to 0 on both header and form

Comment: the margin: 0px and padding: 0px have moved it closer a tiny bit. display inline makes the form disappear weird.

Comment: very weird...try to set a width in the form tag to see where is he

Comment: I have managed to move the form up to the header, so now it sits below the header. but it does not go any higher to be closer to the logo

Comment: .site-title {
    background-image: url("../../Images/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    height: 33px;
    width: 267px;
    margin-top: 28px; 
}

Comment: ok...set on form display inline-block and then set position relative and the set top minus 20px   top: -20px

Comment: The problem is, it has moved to sit below the header. It just doesn't move any further at all, tried all things mentioned on here.

Comment: huummm... have you tried to set in the form position:relative  top: -50px display: inline-block? What is you display on the form? Can you send the website whrre you are working?

Comment: yes I have, I managed to resolve it. I just adjusted the padding-top: 10px; to padding-top: 35px. This moves the logo closer to the login form. I guess this will do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: no problem. Just give a right awnser (ok solution ) in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all use ID's instead of classes. I guess you'll never ever use two header strips or two login forms at the same time.

Easily set the "margin" to 0px. This will remove the distance you actually have.

```
#login {
margin: 0px;

background: url("../../Images/Audi-R8-TDI.jpg");
background-size: 100%;
padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
height: 500px;
width: 1000px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Try to play with that margin in your browser using the built-in "inspector" pressing "F12".

```
margin-top 0px;
```

This will actually just affect the "top" distance.

Study this:
http://www.cssbasics.com/chapter_7_css_margins.html

EDIT:
Even your div's shouldn't be parent

```
<div id="header-strip">..</div>
<div id="login">..</div>
```

Comment: i have tried playing with it using firebug, but any negative values doesnt affect the positon, affects the contents only. positive margin value moves the form down.

Comment: if you want to overlap, you have to set the parents div to "position: relative", set the login to margin-top about 130px, set the header-strip to position:absolute. using position absolute you'll have to use fix size (width and height) and istead of margin "top,left, right and bottom".

Otherwise play with "float", but thats kind a tricky every time!

Answer (score 0):

try to add top margin top .login class

```
.login {
  clear:both;
  margin-top:50px;
  background: url("../../Images/Audi-R8-TDI.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
  border-radius: 5px;
```

}

Comment: No it doesn't overlap the header.

Comment: Oh i thought you want left side code,because you wrote "On the right is how the form appears. And on the left is how it should appear."